# Can't find documentation for any package in R

Tags: r

I've been using R for a while now, but all of a sudden the help() command doesn't work anymore. This is what I get when I try ?tidyverse for instance (the package is obviously installed), but I can't access the documentation for some reason (won't work with ANY package)

> ?tidyverse
> No documentation for ‘tidyverse’ in specified packages and libraries:
> you could try ‘??tidyverse’

I've googled this extensively and I have no idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The command you’ve tested is probably a bad test case: I’m getting the same output, and that’s normal, unless you’ve previously loaded the package. — Did you? Instead, try the help for some built-in function, e.g. `?sum`.

Comment: The package needs to be loaded before you can access the help. But that was always the case in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You might not have loaded the packages. Try

```
library(tidyverse)
?tidyverse
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had every package out of date and just like others commented here I need to have the package updated and loaded before I can access it's documentation. thank you

Comment: The package needs to be loaded, but updating shouldn't be needed.  The most common way to load a package is with `library(pkg)` or `require(pkg)`, but more obscure ways also work, like `requireNamespace("pkg")` or `pkg::somefn`, which make the help available but don't make the functions visible on the search list.